# Why is SQL Server 2008 MD5 displaying foreign characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, md5

```
select cast(hashbytes('md5', 'test') as varchar)
```

displays

```
載쵫ⅆ珓�荎✦
```

but in C#,

```
System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.ComputeHash('test');
```

displays

```
c8059e2ec7419f590e79d7f1b774bfe6
```

which looks to be correct.  Is this a problem with SQL Server's encoding?

Answer (score 2):

`hashbytes` is getting the raw MD5, while C# is returning the base-16 encoded version. (In fact, ComputeHash does the same thing -- you had to do some form of conversion to get it into that base 16 string, didn't you? :) )

Comment: I suppose I did.  How can I display the base-16 encoded version in SQL Server?

Comment: @divided: Unfortunately, I don't know. I don't think you even can without writing the base 16 stuff yourself -- luckily it's easy to do but I don't know Transact enough to be able to write such.